# Creating a method that lists fish from another method

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I am trying to create a method called `listFish()` which lists (using `System.out.println`) all fish in a pond.

I have created a `toString` method that goes as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return("A " + this.size + " cm " + this.species);
}
```

and I also created an `add()` method which takes a single `Fish` parameter and adds that fish to the pond, provided that the pond is not full. If the pond is full to capacity it does nothing. (If it is wrong please tell me):

```
public Fish add(Fish x) {
    if (this.numFish < fishes.length) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I am having trouble with in particular is creating a `listFish()` method, which lists (using `System.out.println`) all fish in the pond as follows: (it gets this information from the test code below)

- A 4cm Sunfish
- A 25 cm Pike
- A 20 cm Bass
- A 30 cm Perch
- A 4 cm Sunfish
- A 15 cm Pike
- A 9 cm Pike
- A 12 cm Bass
- A 5 cm Sunfish
- A 12 cm Sunfish

.

```
 public class PondTestProgram  {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            // Create a pond with 10 fish
            Pond pond = new Pond(15);
            pond.add(new Fish(4, "Sunfish"));
            pond.add(new Fish(25, "Pike"));
            pond.add(new Fish(20, "Bass"));
            pond.add(new Fish(30, "Perch"));
            pond.add(new Fish(4, "Sunfish"));
            pond.add(new Fish(15, "Pike"));
            pond.add(new Fish(9, "Pike"));
            pond.add(new Fish(12, "Bass"));
            pond.add(new Fish(5, "Sunfish"));
            pond.add(new Fish(12, "Sunfish"));
            pond.listFish();
```

I was thinking that the method could look something like this but it has not been working out so far:

```
public void listFish() {
    System.out.println(toString().add());
}
```

so basically it would take the add method and `toString` and print out the fish's length and fish's name but so far I keep getting errors. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hints: Methods need to be called against objects. What object(s) are you asking for its/their `toString()` value? Why are you trying to `add()` something to that returned string?

Comment: Can you give some feedback on the answers?

Comment: none have worked so far @mikeyaworski

Comment: if it helps this is how i started my class:

Comment: public class Pond 
{
  private int numFish;
  private Fish [] fishes;

Comment: and I am just looking to add each of the fish to the array

Comment: You haven't tried hard enough. Actually try the answers, because they suggest using an ArrayList and they should work. You shouldn't be using a regular array. Also, you need to initialize `numFish` in the constructor method.

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong, where should i be placing the array list? I know it should be outside my method, so is there a particular place where it needs to be or is anywhere fine? @mikeyaworski

Comment: @AlexChavez Outside of any methods, but inside the `Pond` class. Go to http://pastie.org and paste all of your code (then send me the link) so I can help you better.

Comment: okay thank you! heres the link http://pastie.org/8689791 @mikeyaworski

Comment: @AlexChavez I've noticed a lot of mistakes. I'll fix these up and explain them in a reply.

Comment: i figured it out thank you! @mikeyaworski

Comment: @AlexChavez Lol alright good thing. Either way, here is the `Pond` class that I modified: http://pastie.org/8689817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep an instance [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and just add fish to the ArrayList when calling the `add` method.

Like so:

```
ArrayList<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<Fish>();

public void add(Fish fish)
{
    // if the ArrayList contains less than the total number of allowed fishes
    if (fishes.size() < this.numFish) {
        fishes.add(fish);
    }
}
```

And then add this method to list all of the fish in the pond (from the ArrayList):

```
public void listFish() {

    // iterate for every fish in the fishes ArrayList
    for (Fish fish : fishes) {
        System.out.println(fish.toString());
    }
}
```

Edit: this is the `Pond` class that I modified with my strategy and with fixed mistakes: http://pastie.org/8689817

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Fish> pond = new ArrayList<Fish>();
```

//add method for adding the fishes in arrayList

```
public void add(Fish x) {
           if (pond.size() < capacity) {
                pond.add(x);
            } 
        }
```

//listFish() method to print the fishes in a pond

```
public void listFish() {
   for (Fish f : pond){
     System.out.println(f.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pond `add` method does not really add fishes to the pond. Make it really add fishes to the pond. Then in `listFish` just loop through the fishes which are already added in the pond and print them.

Comment: how do I make it add to the pond? @peter.petrov

Comment: Keep e.g. an array or ArrayList of fishes as class variable in the pond class. The pond add method should add to this internal (for the pond) array/ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Add should add an item to a list, in this case it looks like fishes.

```
List<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<Fish>();
int numFish = 10; // to keep max size

public void add(Fish x) {
    if (fishes.length < numFish) {
        fishes.add(x);
    }
}
```

And you iterate for each item and print them.

```
public void listFish() {
   for (Fish f : fishes){
     System.out.println(f.toString());
   }
}
```

and also, in Fish class, override toString for your format.

Comment: I doubt this implementation of the add method is OK. It won't even compile.

Comment: `public void ...` and then `return;`

Comment: I just copied from the post, forgot to remove x.